# Slice bounds out of range when trying to pass slices as arguments to a recursive function (Go)

Tags: recursion, go, slice, panic

I'm trying to pass slices as arguments to a recursive function. Since slices are passed as reference, I believe that the recursive function that I'm passing it to should be able to perform the manipulations without any problem. I'm only using append() and therefore shouldn't have a problem with slices having inadequate capacity right?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func allPossiblePaths(arrGraph [8][8]bool, src int, dest int) [][]int {
    var visited []bool //a slice that marks if visited
    var path []int     //a slice to store a possible path
    var paths [][]int  //a slice to store all paths

    visited = make([]bool, 8) //set all nodes to unvisited

    dfs(arrGraph, src, dest, visited, path, paths)

    return paths

}

func dfs(myGraph [8][8]bool, src int, dest int, visited []bool, path []int, paths [][]int) {
    //add current node to path
    path = append(path, src)

    //mark current node as visited
    visited[src] = true

    //if the current node is the destination
    //print the path and return
    if src == dest {

        //make a copy of path slice
        buffer := make([]int, len(path))
        copy(buffer, path)

        //append the copy of path slice into the slice of paths
        paths = append(paths, buffer)

        fmt.Println(path) //Just for debugging purpose
        return
    }

    for i := 1; i <= 7; i++ { //loop through all nodes

        //if ith node is a neighbour of the current node and it is not visited
        if myGraph[src][i] && visited[i] == false {

            // call dfs on the current node
            dfs(myGraph, i, dest, visited, path, paths)

            //mark the current node as unvisited
            //so that we can other paths to the final destination
            visited[i] = false

            //re-slice the slice - get rid of the current node
            path = path[:len(path)-1]
        }

    }

}

func main() {
    var myGraph [8][8]bool //the graph

    //creating the graph
    myGraph[1] = [...]bool{false, false, true, true, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[2] = [...]bool{false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false}
    myGraph[3] = [...]bool{false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false}
    myGraph[4] = [...]bool{false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[5] = [...]bool{false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[6] = [...]bool{false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true}
    myGraph[7] = [...]bool{false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false}

    fmt.Println(allPossiblePaths(myGraph, 1, 7))
}

OUTPUT:
[1 2 3 4 6 7]
[1 2 7]
[1 7]
[3 2 5 7]
[4 6 7]
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x4dc300, 0xc82000a0b0)
        /usr/local/opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
main.dfs(0x0, 0x1000001010000, 0x10001000100, 0x1000100010100, 0x1000001000000, 0x1000000010000, 0x100000101000100, 0x1000000000000, 0x3, 0x7, ...)
        /home/nitrous/src/test2b/main.go:52 +0x480
main.dfs(0x0, 0x1000001010000, 0x10001000100, 0x1000100010100, 0x1000001000000, 0x1000000010000, 0x100000101000100, 0x1000000000000, 0x1, 0x7, ...)
        /home/nitrous/src/test2b/main.go:45 +0x41f
main.allPossiblePaths(0x0, 0x1000001010000, 0x10001000100, 0x1000100010100, 0x1000001000000, 0x1000000010000, 0x100000101000100, 0x1000000000000, 0x1, 0x7, ...)
        /home/nitrous/src/test2b/main.go:12 +0x150
main.main()
        /home/nitrous/src/test2b/main.go:71 +0x423
```

Expected output: (achieved when using global variables instead of passing variables to a function)

[[1 2 3 4 6 7] [1 2 3 6 7] [1 2 5 6 7] [1 3 2 5 6 7] [1 3 4 6 7] [1 3 6 7] [1 6 7]]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling exactly what is the issue:

> panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

Since you are calling the same function iteratively and re-slicing the slice you need to check each time if you reached the slice capacity range, in other terms if the slice pointer is pointing to a valid address (index), otherwise you get the `out of range error` message.

And since you are making a recursive iteration, by decreasing the path length each time, you have to check if the slice index is within a valid range.

```
//re-slice the slice - get rid of the current node
if len(path) > 0 {
       path = path[:len(path)-1]
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pX2TlAP-bp

Comment: Yes, however, the output I'm looking for is all the possible paths from 1 to 7. The expected output is

[[1 2 3 4 6 7] [1 2 3 6 7] [1 2 5 6 7] [1 3 2 5 6 7] [1 3 4 6 7] [1 3 6 7] [1 6 7]]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a pointer to my slice 'path' as an argument to the recursive function. It works now! Thanks anyway.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func allPossiblePaths(arrGraph [8][8]bool, src int, dest int) [][]int {
    var visited []bool //a slice that marks if visited
    var path []int     //a slice to store a possible path
    var paths [][]int  //a slice to store all paths

    visited = make([]bool, 8) //set all nodes to unvisited

    dfs(arrGraph, src, dest, visited, &path, paths)

    return paths

}

func dfs(myGraph [8][8]bool, src int, dest int, visited []bool, path *[]int, paths [][]int) {
    //add current node to path
    *path = append(*path, src)

    //mark current node as visited
    visited[src] = true

    //if the current node is the destination
    //print the path and return
    if src == dest {

        //make a copy of path slice
        buffer := make([]int, len(*path))
        copy(buffer, *path)

        //append the copy of path slice into the slice of paths
        paths = append(paths, buffer)

        fmt.Println(*path) //Just for debugging purpose
        return
    }

    for i := 1; i <= 7; i++ { //loop through all nodes

        //if ith node is a neighbour of the current node and it is not visited
        if myGraph[src][i] && visited[i] == false {

            // call dfs on the current node
            dfs(myGraph, i, dest, visited, path, paths)

            //mark the current node as unvisited
            //so that we can other paths to the final destination
            visited[i] = false

            //re-slice the slice - get rid of the current node

            *path = (*path)[:len(*path)-1]

            //fmt.Println(path)

        }

    }

}

func main() {
    var myGraph [8][8]bool //the graph

    //creating the graph
    myGraph[1] = [...]bool{false, false, true, true, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[2] = [...]bool{false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false}
    myGraph[3] = [...]bool{false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false}
    myGraph[4] = [...]bool{false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[5] = [...]bool{false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[6] = [...]bool{false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true}
    myGraph[7] = [...]bool{false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false}

    fmt.Println(allPossiblePaths(myGraph, 1, 7))
}
```